# Can we use Same domain for a mail server and a website

Tags: server, mail-server

I bought a domain name from google domains i.e abc.com

I want to create a new google workspace with a mail server which has all emails as xyz@abc.com, for creating this google is asking for a domain name (abc.com)

I also want to create a website "abc.com"
Can I create both of the above i.e a mail server and website with same domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can create both. There should not be a problem. Many Google Workspace customers do the same.

Comment: thank you, I have setup a mail server using google workspace